# SharePoint XSL Counter

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, cqwp

So I've been banging my head against the wall for a while and am looking for some help. I'm trying to create a new itemstyle in sharepoint designer that basically checks each item in a task list and then tallies up the total number of Completed, In Progress, and Not Started statuses.  The problem is to my knowledge, xsl doesn't have mutable variables.  What I have so far is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="sChk">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Status"/>
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:for-each select="@Status">
       <xsl:if test="$sChk = 'Completed' ">
           <!-- Add to Completed Counter -->
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="$sChk = 'In Progress' ">
               <!-- Add to In Progress Counter -->
       </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="$sChk = 'Not Started' ">
           <!-- Add to Not Started Counter -->
       </xsl:if>
        <br/>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    Out Of Loop:      
    Total Completed: <!-- Completed Value -->
    Total In Progress: <!-- In Progress Value -->
    Total Not Started: <!-- Not Started Value -->
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: So I've also tried this recursive method as well but this isn't working either...

```
<xsl:param name="cCount" select="0"/>
<xsl:param name="ipCount" select="0"/>
<xsl:param name="nsCount" select="0"/>

<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$sChk = 'Completed'">
        <xsl:call-template name="PSRView2.0">
            <xsl:with-param name="cCount" select="$cCount +1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ipCount" select="$ipCount"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nsCount" select="$nsCount"/>              
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$sChk = 'In Progress'">
        <xsl:call-template name="PSRView2.0">
            <xsl:with-param name="cCount" select="$cCount"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ipCount" select="$ipCount +1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nsCount" select="$nsCount"/>              
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$sChk = 'Not Started'">
        <xsl:call-template name="PSRView2.0">
            <xsl:with-param name="cCount" select="$cCount"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ipCount" select="$ipCount"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="nsCount" select="$nsCount +1"/>               
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$cCount"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ipCount"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nsCount"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that in XSLT variables are immutable. What you need to use in your case those is the **count** function, which counts up all the items in a node-set. Something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="completed" select="count(task[@Status='Completed'])" />
<xsl:variable name="inprogress" select="count(task[@Status='In Progress'])" />
<xsl:variable name="notstarted" select="count(task[@Status='Not Started'])" />
Total: <xsl:value-of select="$completed + $inprogress + $notstarted" />
```

Of course, you would need to replace 'task' with what ever element name you are using in your XSLT.

Without seeing your XML, it is hard to give a precise answer, but as an example, consider the following XML

```
<tasklist>
   <task status="Completed" />
   <task status="Completed" />
   <task status="In Progress" />
</tasklist>
```

Then the XSLT (to get totals only), would look like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:template match="tasklist">
        <xsl:variable name="completed" select="count(task[@Status='Completed'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="inprogress" select="count(task[@Status='In Progress'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="notstarted" select="count(task[@Status='Not Started'])" />
        Total: <xsl:value-of select="$completed + $inprogress + $notstarted" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice how you need to be positioned on the parent element of all the individual 'task' elements here. As an alternative, you can do something like this...

```
<xsl:variable name="completed" select="count(//task[@Status='Completed'])" />
```

Which would count **task** elements wherever they are in the XML.

You could even do the following, if you really didn't know the element name, but were sure there were no other elements with a 'Status' attibute:

```
<xsl:variable name="completed" select="count(//*[@Status='Completed'])" />
```

Comment: Silly question, how do I know what element name I'm using?

Comment: Also, does that mean I DON'T need the for-each loop then?

Comment: Indeed you don't need the for-each loop here, as it is only iterating over one attribute, and doesn't actually use the value of the attribute in the loop anyway. As for the element name, I had assumed you would know the structure of the XML (after all, if you know the attribute is called 'status', you should know what element it belongs too....)

Comment: Well I tried that code out, but I'm just getting the query repeated the number of tasks within the list. Since it is a task list I'm assuming that is the element is the task list or should it be the content type?

Comment: I've expanded on my answer to try and give some further hints.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly but the thing is with this SharePoint CQWP and the count function, something is not adding up. The idea is that the CQWP pulls task items from all task lists within subsites.  I've grouped the query by subsite name. the problem is that it displays n number of the count display (where n is the total number of task items per task list). So if there are 3 task items in a task list, it will display:    "Task Completed: 0 Task Completed: 0 Task Completed: 0"